# Match an input entity with existing entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a WebAPI where the frontend will send back a list of entities. Some of which may already exist.

```
    public void AddTags( List<Tag> tags) //input coming from frontend js
    {
        foreach(Tag tag in tags){
          //check if tag exists in db
          //if not, create one

        }
    }
```

I tried to use `DbContext.Tags.Contains(tag)` but I am not sure how to link `tag` with the existing tag entity in the database.

I am trying to do something  similar to below:

```
Tag tag = new Tag();
tag.name = "foo";
tag.someProp1= "hello";
tag.someProp2= "world";
tag.someProp3= "123";
//tag.id = unique id is unknown, decided by db
//find an identical entity exists in db, link `tag` to it
//if no such entity exists, add to DbContext.Tags
```

I am looking for something like `DbContext.Tags.Match(tag);` Where given an entity, it's looking for an identical one in db.

Comment: Does `Tag` contain a unique identifier?

Comment: Yes it does, but I believe when it's created on js side the uid is null. It is similar to `Tag tag = new Tag()` where you fill out the tag_name but tag_id won't be set until you do SaveChanges().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you.  I assume that `Tag` has some type of unique identifier (either an Id or Name property perhaps).  So you can always do something like this:

`DBContext.Tags.Where(t => t.Id == tag.Id);`

Would that work for you?

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment above, I'm not sure what you are after.  If you are only 'adding' then you don't need to check if the Tags exist, correct?

If you know what you want to match against, you can do this yes?

`DBContext.Tags.Where(t => t.name == tag.name && t.prop1 == tag.prop1).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @Yonk Ok, I'm still not totally clear.  What determines whether one Tag is identical to another Tag?

Comment: @Yonk Do you know all the properties to match against ahead of time?

Comment: yep! all properties are known. I think I get your point now: I should just run a query for every property, and if they all match, i will link to that entity in the db?

Comment: @Yonk yeah, I made another update to my answer along those lines.  You need some way to determine uniqueness and that will form the basis for your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can look the identifier for the tag up in your database, and do this afterwards:

If the entity already exists:

```
context.Tags.Attach(tag);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Otherwise just:

```
context.Tags.Add(tag);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm not sure if you can omit that first check, but at least this will work.